# PanelBox disclosed attribute not works

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

PanelBox component has set the disclosed attribute to "false".

When I disclose one child, after re-logging the entire panel box is disclosed.

If everything is disclosed and I set one child to close, after re-logging everything is closed.

I need PanelBox closed each time I go to that page or log into app.

Maybe it's connected with MDS, but I do not know which configuration should be used  for this particular situation.

I use ADF 11 R1, JSF 1.2 and WebLogic server.

edit
I can show this sample:

```
            <af:panelBox text="#{row.date} - #{row.name}" id="pb1"
                     styleClass="AFStretchWidth" disclosed="false"
                     type="flow">
```

Comment: I think it would be more understandable if you add some code snippets you used.

Comment: I did it. Sorry for  a few lines but I can't show more.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the **disclosed** value in your Bean

```
<af:panelBox text="#{row.date} - #{row.name}" id="pb1"
                     styleClass="AFStretchWidth" disclosed="#{MyBean.isPanelClosed}"
                     type="flow">
```

**In your java code**

```
// Bean Constructor or your custom action listner or action 

public MyBean(){

      ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope().put("myFlag",true);
  }

 private boolean panelClosed=false;


// Setter and getter

public void setPanelClosed(boolean panelClosed) {
    this.panelClosed= panelClosed;
}

public boolean isPanelClosed() {


        boolean tempFlag=false;
        if(null!=ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope().get("myFlag"))
               tempFlag=(boolean)ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope().get("myFlag");

    return tempFlag;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to set attribute for component before load a page.  Is it possible to set attribute for Panel Box in method call (default activity) in taskflow before loading?